# PySpark: how to convert blank to null in one or more columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

For a DataFrame I need to convert blank strings (`''`, `' '`, ...) to null values in a set of columns.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('ball', 'medium', '', 'blue'),
  ('pencil', 'small', '5g', ''),
  ('paper', ' ', ' ', 'white')
], ['product', 'size', 'weight', 'color'])
```

I can do it for each column one by one, but its too lazy when we have many dataframes and columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, trim, col

df = df \
 .withColumn('size', when(trim(col('size')) == '', None).otherwise(col('size'))) \
 .withColumn('weight', when(trim(col('weight')) == '', None).otherwise(col('weight'))) \
 .withColumn('color', when(trim(col('color')) == '', None).otherwise(col('color')))
```

How should I do the transformation in a more generic way, avoiding code replication?

Answer (score 2):

What about this neater one :-)?

```
df.select('*',*[when(trim(df[x])=='',None).otherwise(df[x]).alias(F"{x}_new") for x in df.columns]).show()
```

Or even better

```
df.select(*[when(trim(df[x])=='',None).otherwise(df[x]).alias(x) for x in df.columns]).show()


+-------+------+------+-----+
|product|  size|weight|color|
+-------+------+------+-----+
|   ball|medium|  null| blue|
| pencil| small|    5g| null|
|  paper|  null|  null|white|
+-------+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `DataFrame.replace` function.

```
df.replace(
    to_replace=['', ' '],
    value=None,
    subset=['size', 'weight', 'color']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate in a function and add it to the DataFrame class

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, trim, col
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

def blank_to_null(self, *col_names):
  for col_name in col_names:
     self = self.withColumn(
       col_name,
       when(trim(col(col_name)) == '', None) \
       .otherwise(col(col_name)))
  return self

DataFrame.blank_to_null = blank_to_null
```

Very simple now

```
df = df.blank_to_null('size', 'weight', 'color')
```

[image]

A good practice to extend the DataFrame class is to declare an extension function and add it to a `custom` property

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, trim, col
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

# decorator to attach a function to an attribute
def add_attr(cls):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            f = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return f

        setattr(cls, func.__name__, _wrapper)
        return func

    return decorator

# DataFrame custom functions (blank_to_null)
def custom(self):
    @add_attr(custom)
    def blank_to_null(*col_names):
      df = self
      for col_name in col_names:
         df = df.withColumn(
           col_name,
           when(trim(col(col_name)) == '', None) \
           .otherwise(col(col_name)))
      return df
    
    return custom

# add new property to the Class pyspark.sql.DataFrame
DataFrame.custom = property(custom)
```

Still simple to use

```
df = df.custom.blank_to_null('size', 'weight', 'color')
```